# Is there an equivalent for System.Environment.Machinename which can be used in a portable class library?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, portable-class-library

Or do I need to put this behind an interface and implement this in a platform dependent way?

Comment: It is the NETBIOS name of the machine.  Only desktop machines support that, about as unportable as you can possibly get.

Comment: It is not clear from the question if you are targeting a specific platform. If you are targeting Windows Store apps, you might be able to take advantage of code from the [Q42.WinRT project](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT). Among other functionality, it contains a `Util.GetMachineName()` method.

Comment: With that portable class library I would like to target desktop, store, RT, windows phone. Pretty much anything which can be supported of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to abstract this behind an interface. Which than can be implemented in a platform depended way.